# Rescue RuntimeError in Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, runtime-error

I have a custom Rakefile which calls different `file` tasks. Sometimes a file that is expected doesn't exist, and rake throws a RuntimeError and fails. However, I'd like to do a few things before it fails. So is there any way I could rescue a RuntimeError? Or is there some sort of a magic task which gets called before a complete fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't run into this issue with rake myself, but you could try simply wrapping your call to the `file` tasks in a `begin`-`rescue` block, i.e.

```
begin
  file_task
rescue RuntimeError => e
  puts e
end
```

and then do your rescuing in the `rescue` block.